# no puedo actualizar la pagina en mi codigo

Tags: python, pygame

necesito ayuda, estoy siguiendo los pasos de un canal en youtube para crear un juego y hay una parte en la que hay que actualizar la pantalla, pero en mi caso sigo los pasos y nada pasa, quisiera saber que puedo hacer para que las indicaciones que voy escribiendo se ejecuten en la pantalla
este es el codigo (lo que no me funciona es la parte de `pygame.display.flip()` este es el codigo que se usa para actualizar la pagina.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

# Definir colores
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED= (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE= (0,0,255)

size = (800,500)

# Crear Ventana
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


while True: 
    for  event in pygame.event.get():
     print(event)
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
       sys.exit()
 
 # color de fondo
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    ### ----- ZONA DE DIBUJO
pygame.draw.line(screen, VERDE,[0, 100], [100, 100], 5)


# actualizar pantalla
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Según estoy viendo, la variable VERDE no está definida y obviamente el código de actualizar pantalla nunca se va a ejecutar porque el ciclo while bloquea totalmente la aplicación. Prueba moviendo la parte de actualizar pantalla y la de dibujar la línea ANTES del ciclo while.

Comment: Supongo que el `pygame.draw.line` y el `pygame.display.flip()` va dentro del ciclo, así que por favor, corrige la indentación. En python eso es fundamental.

Comment: Hay varios errores: 1) no está importada la biblioteca sys, 2) has reemplazado GREEN por VERDE y este no está definido,3)la línea  if event.type == pygame.QUIT: y subsiguiente están faltos de una indentación 4)pygame.draw.line(screen, VERDE,[0, 100], [100, 100], 5)# actualizar pantalla pygame.display.flip() tambíen le faltan la indentación.